# Keep only bigest interval in coordinates row in R

Tags: r, dplyr

```
   Groups Name start end  sum
1      G1    A   451 954 1405
2      G1    B   451 951 1402
3      G1    C   451 969 1420
4      G1    D   463 870 1333
5      G1    E   463 888 1351
6      G1    X   230 450  680
7      G1    Z   229 450  681
8      G2    F   119 841  960
9      G2    G   118 842  960
10     G3    H   460 790 1250
11     G3    I   123 300 177
12     G4    J   343 878 1221
13     G4    K   343 878 1221
14     G4    L   320 862 1182
```

And I would like for each Groups to keep only one interval representant (an interval meaning that `df$start` and `df$end` overlaps between rows, I explain:

For exemple in the **G1** there are **2 intervals groups** :

**Interval 1** (with `min = 451` and `max = 969`):

```
Name start end sum
A    451   954 1405
B    451   951 1402
C    451   969 1420
D    463   870 1333
E    463   888 1351
```

Then I tak the bigest `df$sum` (here `1420`)

and

**Interval2**  (with `min = 229` and `max = 450`)

```
Name start end  sum
X    230   450  680
Z    229   450  681
```

Then I tak the bigest `df$sum` (here `681`)

If I do that for the all df I get :

```
   Groups Name start end  sum
3      G1    C   451 969 1420
7      G1    Z   229 450  681
9      G2    G   118 842  960
10     G3    H   460 790 1250
11     G3    I   123 300 177
12     G4    J   343 878 1221
```

Does someone have an idea ?
Here are the  data  :

```
structure(list(Groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4"
), class = "factor"), Name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
13L, 14L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "X", "Z"), class = "factor"), 
    start = c(451L, 451L, 451L, 463L, 463L, 230L, 229L, 119L, 
    118L, 460L, 123L, 343L, 343L, 320L), end = c(954L, 951L, 
    969L, 870L, 888L, 450L, 450L, 841L, 842L, 790L, 300L, 878L, 
    878L, 862L), sum = c(1405L, 1402L, 1420L, 1333L, 1351L, 680L, 
    681L, 960L, 960L, 1250L, 177L, 1221L, 1221L, 1182L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Comment: I suspect that what you need here is an optimization, not a simple filter. While you haven't stated that an overall objective is to maximize the overall sum, I still think this is a ["bin packing problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). There are certainly solutions out there, but because this problem is "NP-hard", they scale poorly and are difficult to make generic and good and fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a data.table approach, make use of intervals...

```
library( intervals )
library( data.table )
setDT( mydata )
#factors are annoying, set to character
mydata[, Groups := as.character( Groups )]
mydata[, Name   := as.character( Name )]
#find the intervals by group
ans <- mydata[, as.data.table(
  intervals::interval_union( 
    intervals::Intervals( as.matrix( .SD ) ) , 
    check_valid = TRUE )) , 
  by = .(Groups), 
  .SDcols = c("start", "end") ]
#set the names right
setnames( ans, old = c("V1", "V2"), new = c("start", "end") )
#create temporary IDs
ans[, id := .I ]
#set a key to perform rowwise operation by EACHI without the formation of groups
setkey(ans, id)
#get max sum and Name by interval (if multiple rows have the same max sum, pick the first)
ans[ans, c("Name", "Sum") := {
  val = mydata[ Groups == i.Groups & start >= i.start & end <= i.end, ]
  list( val[ first( val[, .I[sum == max(sum)] ] ), Name ], max(val$sum) )
  }, by = .EACHI ][,id := NULL][]
```

*output*

```
#    Groups start end Name  Sum
# 1:     G1   229 450    Z  681
# 2:     G1   451 969    C 1420
# 3:     G2   118 842    F  960
# 4:     G3   123 300    I  177
# 5:     G3   460 790    H 1250
# 6:     G4   320 878    J 1221
```

Comment: Woow thank you very much for your time and help !!!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to tweak this with regards to precisely which row you keep from each interval group (is it the row with the largest `sum`, or the longest interval? How do you break ties?).

Sorry if it's a bit arcane - I felt like doing a one-liner.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
dt[order(Groups, end, start),
  i := cumsum(shift(cummax(end), 1, end[1]) < rev(cummin(rev(start)))),
  by = Groups][order(-sum, end-start), .SD[1], keyby = .(Groups, i)][, -'i']
#>    Groups Name start end  sum
#> 1:     G1    Z   229 450  681
#> 2:     G1    C   451 969 1420
#> 3:     G2    F   119 841  960
#> 4:     G3    I   123 300  177
#> 5:     G3    H   460 790 1250
#> 6:     G4    J   343 878 1221
```